# Append CSV output coding issue

Tags: powershell, export, append, addition, output

Hi i created the below script to audit local admin groups on remote hosts. It works fine, but since it only outputs the data after it has went through all the hosts, i am afraid the array will run out of buffer space before it has a chance to export to csv, so i have been trying to have it create and append the output from each host as it goes through the list except i cannot get the headers to display on the first line and append additonal lines below it. Below is the output i get when i try to **append**. The italicized words should be the headers and the other info should be listed in the next row. what am i doing wrong?

@{*Server*=pc1; *Members*=Administrator;*DistinguishedName*=DC=Domain,DC=com

This is how it should look. It looks this way if i dont append and i let it create the csv after it has finished going through the list of hosts

```
Server           Members            DistinguishedName
host1   Administrator;Admin2    DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM





$servers= get-content "C:\Scripts\AD Audits\Local Admin\workstations.txt"
$output = "c:\temp\local admin audit $CurrentDate.csv" 
$results = @()
$disconnected = "Did not respond"
foreach($server in $servers)
{
 $connected = Test-Connection $server -count 1 -quiet
    if ($connected) {
        "$server responded" | Out-File -append "c:\temp\LocalAdmin goodhosts $CurrentDate.txt"}

    else { 
        "$server did not respond" | Out-File -append "c:\temp\LocalAdmin badhosts $CurrentDate.txt"}

$group =[ADSI]"WinNT://$server/Administrators" 
 $members = $group.Members() | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) } 
 $results += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
  DistinguishedName = (get-adcomputer ($server) -properties * | select distinguishedname).distinguishedname
  Server = $server
  Members = $members -join ";"

    }

$results | Export-Csv $Output -NoTypeInformation

}`
```

`if($connected -eq $True) {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DistinguishedName = (Get-ADComputer $_).DistinguishedName
        Server = $_
        Members = $members -join ";"
    }} else {write-host ""}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the pipeline rather than a foreach statement, so each object is written to the file as soon as it's processed.

```
$servers | ForEach-Object{

    $connected = Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $state = if($connected) {"$_ responded"} else {"$_ did not respond"}
    $state | Out-File -Append "c:\temp\LocalAdmin goodhosts $CurrentDate.txt"

    $group =[ADSI]"WinNT://$_/Administrators,group" 
    $members = $group.Members() | ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) } 

    if($connected)
    {
       New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           DistinguishedName = (Get-ADComputer $_).DistinguishedName
           Server = $_
           Members = $members -join ";"
       }
    }

} | Export-Csv $Output -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: that seams to work, except it appears that computers that the script cant connect to, still get written to the csv with false info from the previous host that did respond. The pipeline does make sense though. I am actually starting to understand some of this stuff. Instead of using ($server in $servers), you are using a single entry ($_) for each line.

Comment: You can put the new psobject creation inside an IF statement that checks if the computer in question could be connected.

Comment: That worked perfect! I added the if block modification to the bottom of my original question. It probably was not the cleanest way for me to add it but it worked great. Would there have been a better way for me to do it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, new objects will create only if they could be contacted.